# Boot-repair only gets me back in once

Tags: boot-repair

I have a Samsung Book 9 Ativ Lite.  It came with Windows 8.  I used a liveUSB to install Ububtu 14.04 as the only operating system and so deleting windows 8 (hopefully).
After install, the system booted once correctly, but the next time, did not boot and just said "all boot options tried, press F4 for next ...".
I used boot repair, and again that did work - but only once.  But the next time after I turned the machine on and off I it would not boot correctly and I had the same message.
I've tried every combination I can think of - booting and installing in EFI mode or doing both in the legacy mode.  Safeboot is disabled as are the other options recommended in various places.
Each time - no luck.  And boot repair only ever gets me back in once.
Although boot repair completes, it does give an error message.  Here is the log
http://paste.ubuntu.com/8453446/
Can anyone help?